# django render and validate formset in class based-view (ListView)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have the following class based view that I want to use to render a formset and validate it when it gets submitted through a post method:

The formset renders perfectly. When I submit the form I can read the formset and check it for errors. in the post method of this class -> `errors = backorder_formset.errors`

If I find any errors in the formset, I would like to render the view, but this time with the formset instance, that I read from POST. 
When I call `ctx = self.get_context_data()` form within the post method of the class the following error gets raised from the call `super(MissingProductsListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`: 
**`'MissingProductsListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'`**

It seems like the superclass of Listview performs this call:`queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)`

My question is why am I running in this error? and how could I render this formset with its errors messages to display it in the template after it was posted? I am using Django 1.9.9

```
class MissingProductsListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/purchaseorder/missing_products.html'
    context_object_name = 'backorders'
    model = BackOrder

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        backorder_formset = BackOrderFormset(request.POST)
        errors = backorder_formset.errors

        if backorder_formset.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
        else:
            ctx = self.get_context_data()
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)


    def accumulate_identical_products_from_backorders(self, back_order_list):
        ... some code
        return sorted_accumulated_dict.values()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MissingProductsListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = _("Missing Products")
        if self.request.POST:
            ctx['back_order_formset'] = BackOrderFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            accumulated_backorders_per_product = self.accumulate_identical_products_from_backorders(BackOrder.objects.all())

            back_orders = BackOrderFormset(initial=[{'product_id': backorder_dict['product_id'],
                                                     'product': backorder_dict['title'],
                                                     'quantity': backorder_dict['quantity']} for backorder_dict in
                                                    accumulated_backorders_per_product])
            ctx['back_order_formset'] = back_orders
        return ctx

    def get_queryset(self):
      .. some code
        return backorder_list
```

Comment: have you tried using `try...except`I think you can do it if you got error render template with error massage catches by exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """
    A base view for displaying a list of objects.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        if not allow_empty:
            # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
            # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
            # queryset in memory.
            if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
                is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
            else:
                is_empty = len(self.object_list) == 0
            if is_empty:
                raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.") % {
                    'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
                })
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Basically - you missed this part in the POST handler:

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

And to be honest - I am not quite sure if this is a good idea to add post to the generic ListView in django. It looks more like FormView - but I can be wrong here.

Comment: I was able to not run in the exception when i manually rerender the page and pass the context manually to it llike this : `else: return render(request, self.template_name, {'back_order_formset': backorder_formset})`  
            . Your suggestion using FormView instead of ListView avoids the error that I was running into and  is a better and cleaner solution, thank you!.